# Issue on Get MAX id in websql database using sql proxy

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using web sql for store data in sencha touch.I am facing an issue to get max auto increment id while i adding a new row.i am using following code.but its return "NAN"
not giving max id. while i am using it before adding the value in db its work good.Please help me how i get latest record.
Thanks

```
var maxId = Math.max(myStore.findColumnIndex('id'));

if (myStore.getCount() > 0)
{


var maxId = myStore.getAt(0).get('id'); // initialise to the first record's id value.


 myStore.each(function(rec) // go through all the records


{
maxId = Math.max(maxId, rec.get('id'));


});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch id properties in models are treated as type "auto", so they can handle both numbers and strings for record identifiers. You are attempting to use this id property in a math function (Math.max), which is probably why it's returning NaN. Try converting to numbers (either via Number or parseInt, etc) and seeing if that works, otherwise check the type of the variable right before you run it through the Math.max function (using *typeof* in a log).